# The entire layout is just gone in Visual Studio, How do i bring this back?im a beginner and can't find to reset the window settings for bringing back

Tags: visual-studio

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/doqaW.png)
The entire layout is just gone in Visual Studio, How do i bring this back? i'm a beginner and can't find to reset the window settings for bringing back. I tried different methods of resetting the layout of the entire Visual Studio, I even tried to fresh install it but nothing worked.. How do i fix this please help..

Comment: You have not opened a Solution/Project yet. Click 'File' in the top left and either open an exisiting project or create a new one.